# Check existence of (global) function but disallow implicit conversion

Tags: c++, function, templates, implicit-conversion, c++20

Consider this simple check for whether a (global) function is defined:

```
template <typename T>
concept has_f = requires ( const T& t ) { Function( t ); };
// later use in MyClass<T>:
if constexpr ( has_f<T> ) Function( value );
```

unfortunately this **allows for implicit conversions**. This is obviously a big risk for mess-ups.

**Question: How to check if Function( const T& t ) *'explicitly'* exists?**

Something like

```
if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<decltype( Function( t ) ), void> )
```

should be free of implict conversions, but I can't get it working.

Note: The point of the concept approach was to get rid of old 'detection patterns' and simplify.

Comment: This seems backwards. If it's important to disallow implicit conversions, that seems like `Function`'s job, not `has_f`'s.

Comment: How would a function achieve that?

Comment: try do check this way: `void (*f)(const T& t) = &Function;`.

Comment: trying to make sense of it, but failing. Where? What's `f`?

Comment: Perhaps you could add some examples with specific `Function`s and `T`s that demonstrate what this concept does?

Comment: The answer does not need a concept. Something like `
                if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<decltype( Function( t ) ), void> )` will probably do the job. I just can't get these working together.

Comment: Then the question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe clearly what you want to achieve, and *in addition* show the attempt at a concept solution that you've come up with.

Comment: big edit incoming. No XY or Z

Comment: @non-user38741: "*The point of the concept approach was to get rid of old 'detection patterns' and simplify.*" ... what does this mean? What "detection patterns" are you talking about? I don't understand why you would want to constrain a type like this. Do not treat concepts like base classes. They're *patterns*; let users fulfill those patterns however they like. If you have some template code that calls `Function(t)`, why should that code *care* if an implicit conversion happens or not?

Comment: @non-user38741: "*This is obviously a big risk for mess-ups.*" I see nothing obvious about that. Implicit conversions can be perfectly valid and legitimate for an API, and I don't know why a concept should want to forbid it.

Comment: It's just a simple side effect of the concept/requires syntax that we can now easily detect whether a function exists. Isn't it!? (Obv., there is no actual use of `has_f` as a concept in the general sense)

Comment: @NicolBolas Are you going to answer or just educate in general?

Comment: @non-user38741: "*It's just a simple side effect of the concept/requires syntax that we can now easily detect whether a function exists.*" No. That's not what concepts are for. And indeed, detecting such things is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas just another proof of rule I observed through years of dealing with developers, especially with beginners, which I call Babbage's Nightmare: With every exquisite perfect tool human's brain would conceive there are always many creative ways of misuse to be found.

Comment: Entitlement Nightmare

Answer (score 5):

Before explaining how to do this, I will explain why you *shouldn't* want to do any of this.

You mentioned "old 'detection patterns'" without adding any specifics as to what you are referring to. There are a fair number of idioms C++ users sometimes employ that can do something like detecting if a function takes a particular parameter. Which ones of these count as "detection patterns" by your reckoning is not known.

However, the vast majority of these idioms exist to serve a specific, singular purpose: to see if a particular function call with a given set of arguments is valid, legal C++ code. They don't *really* care if a function exactly takes `T`; testing for `T` specifically is just how a few of those idioms work to produce the important information. Namely whether you can pass a `T` to said function.

Looking for a specific function signature was almost always a means to an end, not the final goal.

Concepts, particularly requires expressions, is the *end itself*. It allows you to ask the question directly. Because really, you don't care if `Function` has a parameter that takes a `T`; you care whether `Function(t)` is legitimate code or not. Exactly how that happens is an implementation detail.

The only reason I can think of that someone might want to constrain a template on an exact signature (rather than an argument match) is to defeat implicit conversion. But you really shouldn't try to break basic language features like that. If someone writes a type that is implicitly convertible to another, they have the right to the benefits of that conversion, as defined by the language. Namely, the ability to use it in many ways as if it were that other type.

That is, if `Function(t)` is what your constrained template code is actually going to do, then the user of that template has every right to provide code that makes that compiler within the limits of the C++ language. Not within the limits of your personal ideas of what features are good or bad in that language.

Concepts are not like base classes, where you decide the exact signature for each method and the user must strictly abide by that. Concepts are patterns that constrain template definitions. Expressions in concept constraints are expressions that you expect to use *in your template*. You only put an expression in a concept if you plan on using it in your templates constrained by that concept.

You don't use a function signature; you *call functions*. So you constrain a concept on what functions can be called with which arguments. You're saying "you must let me do this", not "provide this signature".

---

That having been said... what you want is not generally possible ;)

There are several mechanisms that you might employ to achieve it, but none of them do exactly what you want in all cases.

The name of a function resolves to an overload set consisting of all of the functions that could be called. This name can be converted into a pointer to a specific function signature if and only if that signature is one of the functions in the overload set. So in theory, you might do this:

```
template <typename T>
concept has_f = requires () { static_cast<void (*)(T const&)>(&Function); };
```

However, because the name `Function` is *not* dependent on `T` (as far as C++ is concerned), it must be resolved during the first pass of two-phase name lookup for templates. That means any and all `Function` overloads you intend to care about have to be declared *before* `has_f` is *defined*, not merely instantiated with an appropriate `T`.

I think this is sufficient to declare that this is non-functional as a solution. Even if it worked though, it would only "work" given 3 circumstances:

1. `Function` is known/required to be an actual function, rather than a global object with an `operator()` overload. So if a provider of `T` wants to provide a global functor instead of a regular function (for any number of reasons) this method will not work, even though `Function(t)` is 100% perfectly valid, legitimate, and does none of those terrible implicit conversions that for some reason must be stopped.
2. The expression `Function(t)` is not expected to use ADL to find the actual `Function` to call.
3. `Function` is not a template function.

And not one of these possibilities has anything to do with implicit conversions. If you're going to call `Function(t)`, then it's 100% OK for ADL to find it, template argument deduction to instantiate it, or for the user to fulfill this with some global lambda.

Your second-best bet is to rely on how overload resolution works. C++ only permits a single user-defined conversion in operator overloading. As such, you can create a type which will consume that one user-defined conversion in the function call expression in lieu of `T`. And that conversion should be a conversion to `T` itself.

You would use it like this:

```
template<typename T>
class udc_killer
{
public:
  //Will never be called.
  operator T const&();
};

template <typename T>
concept has_f = requires () { Function(udc_killer<T>{}); };
```

This of course still leaves the standard conversions, so you can't differentiate between a function taking a `float` if `T` is `int`, or derived classes from bases. You also can't detect if `Function` has any default parameters after the first one.

Overall, you're still not detecting the signature, merely call-ability. Because that's all you should care about to begin with.

Comment: *The only reason I can think of that someone might want to constrain a template on an exact signature (rather than an argument match) is to defeat implicit conversion.* - Wow, someone's got the message!

Comment: @non-user38741 If implicit conversion is a problem, then `Function` should not allow conversions. It doesn't make sense to write a check that like... `Function` specifically has the signature `void(int)` - sure, maybe you can write that check, but that check does not prevent you from invoking `Function('a')`. If `Function('a')` is a problem, then you should address that with `Function`.

Comment: Also, Nicol, since you're doing a C cast, your `has_f` is basically trivially true :-) But that's besides the point anyway.

Comment: The `static_cast` will work for function templates with deducible template parameters and captureless lambdas—but that doesn’t make it *good*.