# Use concepts to check if a global function exists

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I can create a concept that checks the existence of a member function called to_string() that returns a std::string in a struct/class.

```
template<typename T>
concept method_to_string = requires(T v)
{
    { v.to_string() } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

I would like create a concept that checks the existence of a global function called to_string that accepts a `T`, and returns a std::string. I fail to do that. I use gcc 10.2 as compiler.

My guess is that i would look like this, but it fails:

```
template<typename T>
concept function_to_string = requires(T v)
{
    to_string(const T&) -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

Comment: What does the existence of this global function depend on?

Comment: @cigien: Why is the existence of that function supposed to depend on other things?

Comment: @einpoklum Concepts constrain types. I'm not sure what is being constrained here.

Comment: Ok, I see, the `T` is a parameter. I edited the question slightly, hope that's ok.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63385719/check-existence-of-global-function-but-disallow-implicit-conversion and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146257/c20-concept-which-requires-the-existence-of-an-exact-function-signature should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
template<typename T>
concept method_to_string = requires(T v)
{
    { to_string(v) } -> std::same_as<std::string>;
};
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7WdTjf

Comment: Yes, that one works. It is the other concept that is the problem to solve.

Comment: @mlom Im not sure what other concept you are referring to: "I would like create a concept that checks the existence of a global function called to_string that accepts a T, and returns a std::string". The `{ to_string(v) }` part checks for a global function.

Comment: @mlom Okay no worries :)